# AngularJS call function when redirecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table of tests in `/tests`, and I want to be able to permanently hide a specific test by going to `/tests/:id/hide`. I have a function that does this, I just need to figure out a way to call it without having to invoke a new controller. When doing this, I also want to redirect back to `/tests`.

```
angular.module('WebApp.services', []).
    factory('riakAPIService', function($http) {
        var riakAPI = {};
        riakAPI.hideTest = function(key) {
            return $http({
                // Some code for setting a "hide" flag for this test in the database
            });
        }
    });
```

Is there a pretty way to call `riakAPI.hideTest(id)` when the user goes to `/tests/:id/hide`?

```
angular.module('WebApp', ['WebApp.controllers','WebApp.services','ngRoute']).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when("/tests", {templateUrl: "partials/tests.html", controller: "testsController"}).
            when("/tests/:id", {templateUrl: "partials/test.html", controller: "testController"}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/tests'});
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use the resolve param here .

```
$routeProvider.when('/tests/:id',{
    templateUrl : 'partials/tests.html',
    controller : 'testController',
    resolve : {
        hidden : function(riakAPIService){
              return riakAPIService.hideTest();
        }
    }
})
```

And for the service

```
angular.module('WebApp.services', []).
    factory('riakAPIService', function($http,$location) {
        var riakAPI = {};
        riakAPI.hideTest = function(key) {
            return $http({
                // Some code for setting a "hide" flag for this test in the database
            }).then(function(){
                $location.path('/tests');
            });
        }
    });
```